# Вывести полное название товаров в SQLite+Python

Tags: python, sqlite

```
user_request=input("Введите название товара: ")
db=sqlite3.connect("ostatki.db")
cur=db.cursor()
result=cur.execute(f"SELECT ostatki_tovarov FROM  ostatki_tovatov WHERE nazvanie_tovara MATCH 
(?)",(user_request,)) 
for i in result:
    print(f"{user_request}:{i}")

db.close()
```

Есть такой код.
Мне нужно когда юзер вводить например такой запрос "Травертин", ответ должен быть:

1. Травертин внутренний 50 кг
2. Травертин фасадный 20 кг

и так далее. То есть вывести полное название товара.

А сейчас на выходе:

1. Травертин 50 кг
2. Травертин 20 кг.

Спасибо.

Comment: Вот что просите, то сервер и отдаёт. Посмотрите, как правильно называется поле, из которого надо брать значение.

Comment: у меня поиск по частям.

Comment: Ну и выдача полностью соответствует запросу. Я не понимаю сути претензий к серверу... PS. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169)

Comment: суть вопроса, вывести все товары которые содержать текст запроса.

Comment: Выведите в запросе поле, по которому делаете поиск. Сейчас это разговор ни о чём.

Comment: я Вас не поняла

Comment: ВЫ выполняете поиск по полю `nazvanie_tovara`. Так вот выведите именно его:  `SELECT nazvanie_tovara FROM ostatki_tovatov WHERE nazvanie_tovara MATCH (?)`.